# How to fit an inserted pdf page to the paper size disconsidering the margins?

Tags: graphics, margins, pdfpages, include

I'm writing a document in A4 paper size with specified margins. I want to insert a pdf page from an external document. This external document page size is 13.97 x 21.59 cm. I'd like to insert this page disconsidering the margins and occuping the whole paper width or paper height (depending of the scalation). However all my attempts are inside the margins or outside them. How can I fit the 7th page of [this](https://www.mpbio.com/includes/protocol/FastDNA%20Spin%20Kit%20for%20soil.pdf) document correctly in my text?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,graphics}
\usepackage[%
left=3.00cm,
right=2.00cm,
top=3.00cm,
bottom=2.00cm
]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,page=7]{pdf-FastDNA-Spin}\par
%
\includegraphics[height=\textheight,page=7]{pdf-FastDNA-Spin}\par
%
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,page=7]{pdf-FastDNA-Spin}\par
%
\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,page=7]{pdf-FastDNA-Spin}
\end{document}
```

**Extra questions** Why the first page is empty? How can I remove the page numbering in the page where the pdf is inserted but continue numbering the whole document?

Example of `\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,page=7]{pdf-FastDNA-Spin}`

[image]

Comment: You may use something like a TikZ overlay.

Comment: @TeXnician could you post an example?

Comment: `\usepackage{tikz}` and then in the document `\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[height=\textheight,page=7]{yourfilehere}};` (remember to do necessary page breaks).

Comment: Isn't this precisely what the pdfpages package does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the empty first page because your graphic is a bit too large to fit on the page and so TeX moves it to the next page to try if it fits there. Then it gives up, inserts the graphic and complains:

```
  Overfull \vbox (0.80116pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []
```

Beside this: Use the `pdfpages` package to insert your PDF. The package has lots of options to configure the input. It will also suppress the page number (by setting `\thispagestyle{empty}`).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,graphics}
\usepackage[%
left=3.00cm,
right=2.00cm,
top=3.00cm,
bottom=2.00cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=7]{FastDNA}
\includepdf[pages=7,noautoscale]{FastDNA}
\includepdf[pages=7,fitpaper=true]{FastDNA} %changes paper size

\end{document}
```